# Mostrar información en grafico scatter

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Tengo problemas para mostrar los legend en un scatter.

[Datos utilizados para el ejemplo](https://github.com/theengineeringworld/statistics-using-python/blob/master/gapminder.xls)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import re
import mailbox
import csv
from IPython import display
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
%matplotlib inline

datos = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/theengineeringworld/statistics-using-python/master/gapminder.xls')
datosDos = datos.dropna()
datosDos.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Estoy usando la siguiente función:

```
def plotyearDinamico(anio):

    data = datosDos[datosDos.year == anio]
    area = 10e-6 * datosDos.population
    color = data.region.map({'Africa': 'skyblue', 'Europe' : 'gold', 
    'America' : 'palegreen', 'Asia' : 'coral'})

    data.plot.scatter('babies_per_woman', 'age5_surviving', s = area, c = 
    color, linewidth = 1, edgecolors = 'k', figsize=(9,6))

    pp.axis(ymin = 50, ymax = 105, xmin = 0, xmax = 8)
    pp.xlabel('babies_per_woman')
    pp.ylabel('age5_surviving')
```

Luego llamando a esa funcion veo el siguiente grafico:

```
interact(plotyearDinamico, anio=widgets.IntSlider(min=1950, max=2015, 
step=1, value= 1950))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Se que es un legend() pero no encuentro como ponerlo en este gráfico.**

Fuente: [Ejemplo de lo que necesito](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-with-legend-py)

**¿Como puedo hacer para mostrar los nombres de los continentes ya que solo los tengo diferenciados por colores? Algo mas o menos asi:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import rand

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for color in ['red', 'green', 'blue']:
    n = 750
    x, y = rand(2, n)
    scale = 200.0 * rand(n)
    ax.scatter(x, y, c=color, s=scale, label=color,
           alpha=0.3, edgecolors='none')

ax.legend()
ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si agrego a mi grafica pp.legend(data.region), muestra lo siguiente (El area y color concuerdan pero solo trae uno solo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varios cambios a tu código:

```
def plotyearDinamico(anio):

    data = datosDos[datosDos.year == anio]

    colores = {'Africa': 'skyblue', 'Europe' : 'gold', 
               'America' : 'palegreen', 'Asia' : 'coral'}


    pp.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 8] # Config. tamaño de gráfica
    fig, ax = pp.subplots()
    for region, color in colores.items():

        # Subgráficas por region
        data_region = data[data.region == region]
        area = 10e-6 * data_region.population
        paises_colors = data_region.region.map(colores)

        ax.scatter(x=data_region.babies_per_woman, 
                   y=data_region.age5_surviving, 
                   c=color, 
                   s=area, 
                   label=region, 
                   linewidth = 1,
                   alpha=0.7,
                   edgecolors='k')

    pp.axis(ymin = 50, ymax = 105, xmin = 0, xmax = 8)
    pp.xlabel('babies_per_woman')
    pp.ylabel('age5_surviving')

    # Configuración del tamaño de las leyendas
    lgnd = pp.legend(loc="lower left", scatterpoints=1, fontsize=10)
    for handle in lgnd.legendHandles:
        handle.set_sizes([50.0])

    pp.grid(True)
```

- El principal cambio significativo es que, en vez de hace una única gráfica, hacemos sub-gráficas por region, por lo cual tendremos que hacer un subconjuno de datos, con: `data_region = data[data.region == region]`
- Usamos directamente el metódo `scatter` de `matplotlib` por lo que deberemos configurar adecuadamente los parámetros `x` e `y`, mediante: `x=data_region.babies_per_woman, y=data_region.age5_surviving`
- En este tipo de gráfico es recomendable configurar algo de transparecia mediante `alpha=0.7`, para poder apreciar las superposiciones (algo al menos)
- Al graficar por región, la leyenda se configura directamente mediante `label=region`, `region`en este caso es una cadena con el nombre de la misma.
- por defecto, el tamaño de los círculos se adapta al tamaño al área de cada región, lo que no queda bien, la última parte del código es para configurara un tamaño fijo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracia Patricio!

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tu código es correcto, pero los labels están vacios, no se definen los textos.

Te paso este ejemplo: 
https://www.dkrz.de/up/services/analysis/visualization/sw/ncl/examples/source_code/dkrz-ncl-scatter-plot-with-legend-example

Donde se vé que hay que definir los textos antes de mostrarlo:

```
;-- set explicit labels for legend
    labels = (/"data 1","data 2"/)
```

Notá que estos labels si aparecen en el grafico:

```
 pp.xlabel('babies_per_woman')
 pp.ylabel('age5_surviving')
```

---

ahora veo más claro, me parece que

```
pp.legend(data.region)
```

Carga un solo label y no el array. Debería cargar todo el array.

Comment: No comprendo como anexarlo, por otro lado los labels estan ok y son la info que se analiza, pero lo que quiero mostrar en el legend es la region mostrando el color donde se analiza la info por bebes por mujeres y cuantos vivieron mas de 5 años. Por ejemplo en el legend tendria que salir Europa y en un circulo el color amarillo / gold

Comment: para que me entiendas lo que quiero decir, Decime en tu código donde está escrito el texto del label qyue dice el texto que queres mostrar. Yo creo que no lo tienes.

Comment: Por ejemplo, Muestrame donde defines el texto Europa-Amarillo

Comment: Ah, veo que modificaste y lo marcaste, 
Ok

Comment: Si, eso ya estaba, puse para ver que salia, el tamaño del circulo es por el total de datos, o sea, así como esta no sirve, no se como agregarlo de otra forma

Comment: Prueba de poner: pp.legend({'a','b','c'}) a ver si salen 3 etiquetas

Comment: No, sale lo mismo que el ultimo print que puse en la pregunta solo que en vez de Asia dice a, asi que calculo que el hecho de que este mostrando el area mas el color correcto es suerte en ese print

Comment: pensando... a ver si lo veo